# Call javascript custom function from ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a custom function written in javascript, like:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

I want above `myFunction()` called from `ExtJS`, can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you trying to call myFunction() inside Ext.js? What is the load order of your scripts?

Comment: if you need to invoke a pure javascript function inside an ExtJS event handler (that is javascript) i don't know where is the matter. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ub

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some JS functions to your application to use it on demand I think best approach is to add it to a singleton class (component), example:

```
/**
 * Define some useful javascript functions, common for whole project
 */
Ext.define('MyApplication.lib.MyFunctions', {
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.lib.MyFinctions',

    singleton: true,

    myFunction: function (a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
});
```

After it you can use it as follows:

```
Ext.lib.MyFunctions.myFunction(2, 3);
```